# UITextView Interface Builder MultiLine Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, interface-builder, uitextview

I am using a UITextView in Interface Builder and have typed a hunk of text into it and there are lots of lines breaks in it, blank lines. I did this by typing into it and alt-returning to get a new line.

However when built and run on my device none of these line breaks are seen. Any tips? Anyone heard of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to Write in Attribute Inspector.. It wil work fine..

Comment: Do you use `\n` for newline? Because I cannot replicate the problem that you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

In the header file:

```
IBOutlet UITextView * textview;
```

In the implementation file:

```
textview.text = @"First line\nSecond line\n\nThere is a blank line above\n\tTabbed line";
```

Don't forget to link the `UITextView` with the element in the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Write the text into a text file. And use a line of code to load the file's content into your UITextView. Much easier if you have a lot of text to input.